# Series solution of first order differential equation with constant term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I am curious about whether one can find a series solution to the differential equation $$y’=f(y,t)+k \   \          \      \     k \in \mathbb{R}$$

I know the standard way of solving a differential equation using power series is to arrange it into the form $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty[g(a_{n+1},a_n,...)]t^n=0$$ and then find a recurrence relation. However, I am not sure if writing my above differential equation in the form $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty[g(a_{n+1},a_n,...)]t^n=k$$ Will give me a recurrence relation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is $f?$ We'll be able to help you more if you provide that.

Comment: @AdrianKeister the problem I was originally faced with was $y’=2y^2-3y+2$

Comment: Well, that's separable, so I would solve it that way.

Comment: Making $Y = y + k t$ we have $\dot Y = f(Y,t)$

Comment: @AdrianKeister the exercise was to find a series solution to this problem without other methods

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, the tricky part is here is in squaring the series. Once you've written down your $y$ in series form, you have to differentiate it and square it, in order to solve your DE.